# How can I get backup of my 1 year old site?

Tags: wordpress, backup, cdn

I had a good active site about an two year ago, I was running that site actively, I wrote more than 300 articles on that site and was getting 1k+ traffic daily. Last year, I was too busy with study and other stuff, I totally forgot about site and even didn't renewed the domain and hosting. My hosting account got locked since I wasn't paying the bills. This year I am free and started working online, I have renewed my hosting and activated my domain. I asked 1and1 customer support to give me backup of everything I had on the site, they say 'there are no longer available backups on the server for the deleted contract'. I badly need all of those contents I wrote on that site. The site was created with WordPress and I used Cloudflare CDN, I haven't any backup of the site on my computer.

I am wondering, is there any way to get backup of my site from anywhere?

Comment: Did you try https://web.archive.org ?

Comment: I saw my site on archive that is little broken.

Comment: Your only other hope is via legal means since the law in most countries does require that they maintain logs of activity in case there is an investigation. At any rate this really isn't a programming question.

Comment: I know it's not programming question but I badly need help that'swhy I asked, I think somone in stackoverflow can suggest me some good.

Comment: You need to re develop the website and copy as much as possible from wayback machine ( web.archieve.org ) .

Comment: Can you please know me how can I copy contents from wayback machine?

Comment: Just copy and paste, it's not ideal but honestly there isn't a more efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume your only hope is to try and find your site on the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/). The Wayback Machine is an amazing resource that has been archiving the broader internet since the late 90's. Its not a perfect copy but for static sites like blogs with enough traffic to have been noticed by the web spider that archives it can work rather well. It's also a cool nostalgic trip down memory lane :)